# What kind of effect is this? Sounds like a mix of wah-wah and phaser

Tags: guitar, effects

This [song](https://youtu.be/UIgkk311Ej8?t=95) has a part at 1:35 which has an effect I've heard in many bands (especially psych rock). To me it sounds like a mix of wah-wah and phaser, or some kind of a filter. I couldn't get the same effect by just using the wah-wah. Could this be an expression pedal connected to a phaser pedal, or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a low pass filter, very commonly used in electronic music. Note however that questions about transcribing and identifying equipment are off-topic, please see the help center.

Comment: @user1079505 I’m not actually sure if this fits the bill here. This is not really a question about identifying equipment, but about how a specific effect is achieved, which I think could to some extent be a fair question, though not necessarily on topic.

Comment: Can't listen at the moment but the OP should check to see if this is some form of "Flanger" pedal or effect. Flangers are different than typical phase pedals and can have signal feedback chain that can be manipulated to to make wah-like resonance.